# What type of list should I use when trying to swap elements in a two-dimensional array?

Tags: java

The purpose of this program is to "encrypt" a keyword - the keyword being a user input - by taking two letters at a time (from the keyword), locating these two letters in certain quadrants and essentially swapping them with letters from two other quadrants. I have declared a two-dimensional array named `matrix`. There are four distinct quadrants (5 x 5) in this array - two of the quadrants (top left and bottom right) contain the letters A - Z (excluding J) in an ordered manner. The other two quadrants (top right and bottom left) contain the letters A - Z (again, excluding J) in an unordered manner. The program is basically meant to take in the keyword and iterate through it two characters at a time. This is done with a for loop:

```
for (bytegram = 0; bytegram < length; bytegram += 2) {
            x = keyword1.toUpperCase().charAt(bytegram);
            y = keyword1.toUpperCase().charAt(bytegram + 1);
        }
```

Once it has done this, it will then find the corresponding letters in the top left and bottom right quadrants and then swap them with corresponding letters in the top right and bottom left quadrants. For example, let's say the user entered the keyword ***"than"***. It would deal with ***"th"*** first since it iterates through the keyword two characters at a time. It will find the letter ***"t"*** in the top left quadrant and find the letter ***"h"*** in the bottom right quadrant. To encrypt these two letters, it would essentially swap the columns that ***"t"*** and ***"h"*** are located in and go to the same row, but this time in the top right and bottom left quadrants, as so:

[image: Encryption example]

The two top quadrants correspond with each other and the two bottom quadrants correspond with each other. By this logic, the output (encryption) would be ***"ES"***, as you can see from the picture.

I am having trouble printing out the encryption of a keyword. The program is able to take in a keyword, split it into characters using a character array and iterate through the characters two at a time (using the for loop above). Below that for loop, there are two other for loops which deal with the logic of swapping the letters. Currently, I am stuck on what type of list to use:

```
list[counter] = matrix[a][d];
counter++;

list[counter] = matrix[c][b];
counter++;
```

***"a"*** and ***"b"*** correspond with the top left and bottom right quadrants, and ***"c"*** and ***"d"*** correspond with the top right and bottom left quadrants, respectively.

I have tried ***ArrayList< Character > list = new ArrayList< Character >()*** and ***List< Character > list = new ArrayList< Character >()***. No matter which one I use, I keep getting the error:

> The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to
>   ArrayList

Below is my code thus far:

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class FourSquareCipher {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
        char[][] matrix = { 
                { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',  'Z', 'G', 'P', 'T', 'F' },
                { 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K',  'O', 'I', 'H', 'M', 'U' },
                { 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',  'W', 'D', 'R', 'C', 'N' },
                { 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U',  'Y', 'K', 'E', 'Q', 'A' },
                { 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',  'X', 'V', 'S', 'B', 'L' },
                { 'M', 'F', 'N', 'B', 'D',  'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' },
                { 'C', 'R', 'H', 'S', 'A',  'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K' },
                { 'X', 'Y', 'O', 'G', 'V',  'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P' },
                { 'I', 'T', 'U', 'E', 'W',  'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U' },
                { 'L', 'Q', 'Z', 'K', 'P',  'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' } 
                };

        String fileName = "keywords.txt";
        String line = null;

        String keyword1;
        int length;
        int bytegram;
        int a, b, c, d;
        int i, j;
        int counter;
        char x = 0, y = 0;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long startTimeSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(startTime);

        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner keywordInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the first keyword: ");
        keyword1 = keywordInput.nextLine();
        length = keyword1.length();

        char[] words = keyword1.toUpperCase().toCharArray();

        for (char letter:words) {
            System.out.println(letter);
        }

        for (bytegram = 0; bytegram < length; bytegram += 2) {
            x = keyword1.toUpperCase().charAt(bytegram);
            y = keyword1.toUpperCase().charAt(bytegram + 1);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j] == x && i < 5 && j < 5) {
                    a = i;
                    b = j;
                }
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j] == y && i > 4 && j > 4) {
                    c = i;
                    d = j;
                }
            }
        }

        list[counter] = matrix[a][d];
        counter++;

        list[counter] = matrix[c][b];
        counter++;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            char[] fileToChar = line.toUpperCase().toCharArray();

            for (char fileArray:fileToChar) {
                System.out.println(fileArray);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Encryption time (s): " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeSeconds) / 1000000000 / 1000));
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need random access, you should use an `ArrayList`. And use its `get()` method instead of the array syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will throw an error because,

> list : java.util.ArrayList **NOT EQUAL** matrix : char[][]

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me how would I go about fixing this? Or at least, point me in the right direction?

Comment: Instead of **list[counter] = matrix[a][d];** change to **list.add(matrix[a][d]);** and also instead of **list[counter] = matrix[c][b];** change to **list.add(matrix[c][b]);**

Comment: Vote for the answer brother.